# xna orbit camera troubles

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, camera

I have a `Model` named `cube` to which I load in `LoadContent()`: `cube = Content.Load<Model>("untitled");`.

In the `Draw` Method I call `DrawModel`:

```
    private void DrawModel(Model m, Matrix world)
    {
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in m.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.View = camera.View;
                effect.Projection = camera.Projection;
                effect.World = world;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

`camera` is of the `Camera` type, a class I've setup.  Right now it is instantiated in the initialization section with the graphics aspect ratio and the translation (world) vector of the model, and the Draw loop calls the `camera.UpdateCamera();` before drawing the models.

```
class Camera
{
    #region Fields
    private Matrix view; // View Matrix for Camera
    private Matrix projection; // Projection Matrix for Camera
    private Vector3 position; // Position of Camera
    private Vector3 target; // Point camera is "aimed" at
    private float aspectRatio; //Aspect Ratio for projection
    private float speed; //Speed of camera
    private Vector3 camup = Vector3.Up;
    #endregion

    #region Accessors
    /// <summary>
    /// View Matrix of the Camera -- Read Only
    /// </summary>
    public Matrix View
    {
        get { return view; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Projection Matrix of the Camera -- Read Only
    /// </summary>
    public Matrix Projection
    {
        get { return projection; }
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Camera.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="AspectRatio">Aspect Ratio to use for the projection.</param>
    /// <param name="Position">Target coord to aim camera at.</param>
    public Camera(float AspectRatio, Vector3 Target)
    {
        target = Target;
        aspectRatio = AspectRatio;
        ResetCamera();
    }

    private void Rotate(Vector3 Axis, float Amount)
    {
        position = Vector3.Transform(position - target, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Axis, Amount)) + target;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resets Default Values of the Camera
    /// </summary>
    private void ResetCamera()
    {
        speed = 0.05f;
        position = target + new Vector3(0f, 20f, 20f);
        projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, aspectRatio, 0.5f, 100f);
        CalculateViewMatrix();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the Camera.  Should be first thing done in Draw loop
    /// </summary>
    public void UpdateCamera()
    {
        Rotate(Vector3.Right, speed);
        CalculateViewMatrix();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the View Matrix for the camera
    /// </summary>
    private void CalculateViewMatrix()
    {
        view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(position,target, camup);
    }
```

I'm trying to create the camera so that it can orbit the center of the model.  For a test I am calling `Rotate(Vector3.Right, speed);` but it rotates almost right but gets to a point where it "flips."  If I rotate along a different axis `Rotate(Vector3.Up, speed);` everything seems OK in that direction.

So I guess, can someone tell me what I'm not accounting for in the above code I wrote?  Or point me to an example of an orbiting camera that can be fixed on an arbitrary point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you might be rotating around Vector3.Right to give your camera the freedom to change pitch.

As you pitch(orbit) around your object, getting to the very top, if you then pitch some more, your camera would be upside down as it follows the orbit path. But since you have Vector3.Up (camup) as the 3rd param in your createlookat method, it is being told to always stay right side up relative to Vector3.Up. So instead of allowing the camera to proceed upside down, it flips it over as it continues the orbit path.

Most games limit the max pitch to somewhere between +89 & -89 degrees to keep the flip from happening.

Comment: Yea, I see what you mean now.  At first it was hard for me to get a grasp on it.  I decided to `clamp` on the pitch in the interval [-80,80].  Seemed to make the most sense.

Comment: Or you can rotate the Up vector also. Then you will be able to orbit all around vertically without any issues.